# How to pass multiple regex in single re.complile and create list of matched pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have written multiple regex patterns separately and tried to make the matched patterns in a list like this below:

```
pattern=re.compile('(?:OR011-|OGEA|LLCM|A|1-)\d{2,15}')
```

For a single pattern I am able to make the match patterns to list like this on a column but not for entire as whole:

```
pattern_list=list(filter(pattern1.findall, column))



input column like this:

column
OR011-103401461251
Hi the information is 1-234455
How are you?LLCM23466723

output coming:
['OR011-103401461251','Hi the information is 1-234455','How are you?LLCM23466723']

output required:
['OR011-103401461251','1-234455','LLCM23466723']
```

How can I compile all patterns in a single re.compile() and make a single pattern_list for all the matched patterns?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what your _goal_ is, could you detail a little bit? And what kind of object is `column`? What about collapsing all your expressions with pipes, like `pattern=re.compile('|'.join([expr1, expr2, ...]))` ?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong 'Column' is dataframe column which i have converted to string on which I wantthese regular expressions to fetch the matching patterns and append that to list. Updated the how column looks

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong any idea? also regex is not reading the pattern where the junk data such as ```'How are you?LLCM23466723'``` is there

Comment: you should use `re.search`, not `re.match`. Also if your data is originally a dataframe (from Pandas I suppose), I would suggest to take advantages of the methods it provides, such as [`dataframe[colname].str.match()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) or `...str.contains()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to combine your expressions to 1 pattern:

```
(?:OR011-|OGEA|LLCM|A|1-)\d{2,15}
```

Explanation

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `OR011-|OGEA|LLCM|A|1-` Match 1 of the options
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\d{2,15}` Match 2-15 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Z7LdO/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qmu5ju)

**About your approach**

The function [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns the element for which the function returns true. You pass the method [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to filter where, for every item, findall finds a match and returns the element which will result in:

```
['OR011-103401461251','Hi the information is 1-234455','How are you?LLCM23466723']
```

What you could do instead of using filter is to use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and pass findall:

```
pattern=re.compile('(?:OR011-|OGEA|LLCM|A|1-)\d{2,15}')
pattern_list=map(pattern.findall, df.column)
print(list(pattern_list))
```

That will result in:

```
[['OR011-103401461251'], ['1-234455'], ['LLCM23466723']]
```

See a [Python example](https://repl.it/repls/GigaBelovedLesson)

Or you could pass a lambda to map and first check if the search has a result:

```
pattern=re.compile('(?:OR011-|OGEA|LLCM|A|1-)\d{2,15}')
pattern_list=map(lambda x: pattern.search(x).group() if pattern.search(x) else None, df.column)
print(list(pattern_list))
```

That will result in:

```
['OR011-103401461251', '1-234455', 'LLCM23466723']
```

See a [Python example](https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulCyberInsurance)

Comment: problem i am facing is I am not able to retrive the matching pattern when the pattern is in some string for example in above case I am getting the list as ```['OR011-103401461251','Hi the information is 1-234455','How are you?LLCM23466723']``` when I use ```search``` and just ```['OR011-103401461251']``` when i use ```match``` . How to get the list as ```['OR011-103401461251','1-234455','LLCM23466723']``` ? Need insights on this

Comment: @SachinKumar You could use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) See https://ideone.com/qmu5ju

Comment: I tried using ```re.findall``` as well but the result remains the same as of what i got from ```search``` , it gives the entire string where the pattern is encountered and not the pattern itself

Comment: updated the output in question as well @the fourth bird

Comment: its working if taken as dataframe.....is there a way in which I can get the same with my way specific. Also can you help me understand why for my piece of code it is taking the entire string as match?

Comment: @SachinKumar I have updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks buddy..it worked with minor alterations, most importantly difference in using map and filter